# FLUME for per-5-min data ingestion

Tags: twitter, flume, sentiment-analysis

I have created a project for Twitter Sentiment analysis and it is working fine. This is a brief of what the flow is:

Twitter -> FLUME hourly data -> HDFS -> Hive Table for Hourly data using partition -> Extract/clean/transform and load data into Oracle Table using UNIX Script/SQL Loader -> BO/Tableau for dashboard.

As seen above, the only issue is - it is not real time.

I would like to extract tweets for every 5 minutes using FLUME and then change the workflow accordingly.

I have done some research on the Internet but could not find any example/use-case wherein we can configure FLUME to take data for every 5 minutes. I can take data for every 1 minute though, but that's not what I would like to do.

Any pointers to this matter will really be useful!!

Regards,
Suddhasatwa